# Append javascript variable to href folder path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have a javascript code that extracts filename as a variable from the current html file.

```
var filename=location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
console.log(filename);
```

The filename for example is "new.html"

I need to append this variable to a folder path with href tag for  opening another file file with that variable name in a new tab. I have tried concatenation but it doesn't work.

```
<a href="Foldername/'+filename+'" target="_blank">
```

Any help on this would be appreciated! Thank you!

Edit:  I have posted the second part of my problem as another question on SO. Thank you for the help!

Comment: `document.querySelector("a").href = "Foldername/" + filename;`

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service; Please update your question with the code you've tried so far.

Comment: You just want to create a string with the content of `<a href="Foldername/filename" target="_blank">` or an html element?

Comment: @Soviut OP has included the code that they have tried at Question

Comment: You should have added both parts here

Answer (score 5):

Give an Id to your a tag

**Html:**

```
<a href="#" id="atag" target="_blank">
```

**Javascript:**

```
var filename=location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
document.getElementById("atag").href= "Foldername/"+filename;
```

Comment: Quick and clean

Comment: Wow! This helped! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var filename=location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = `Foldername/${filename}`;
anchor.target = '_blank';
```

Then you can append your `anchor` element wherever you want in your html.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this using Javascript then do this way -

```
var filename=location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
console.log(filename); 

var html = "<a href='Foldername/'"+filename+" target='_blank'> "

el.innerHTML = html// el is the wrapper of anchor element.
```

If you want to keep the anchor tag in HTML code then -

Give a id/class to anchor -
HTML -

```
<a href="" id="anchor" target="_blank">
```

JS -

```
var anchor = document.getElementById("anchor");

anchor.setAttribute("href", "Foldername/" + filename)
```